# Performing np.isnan on Keras model weighta fails with TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Team:

I am writing a custom callback function to stop terminate my model when there is a NaN value in Keras model weights.

```
import numpy as np
class TerminateNaN(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):        
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        mod_weights = np.asarray(model.get_weights())
        if mod_weights is not None:
            if np.isnan(mod_weights):
              print("Invalid weight and terminated at epoch {}".format(epoch))
              self.model.stop_training = True
        # mod_weights = np.asarray(model.get_weights())
        # print(f"Type of weights {type(mod_weights)}")
        # # print(f"Type of weights {type(mod_weights)}")
        # print(f"Weights:::: {mod_weights}")
```

Mode:

```
%mkdir model_save
input_layer = Input(shape=(2))
layer1 = Dense(32,activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(0,1,seed=30))(input_layer)
layer2 = Dense(28,activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(0,1,seed=30))(layer1)
layer3 = Dense(16,activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(0,1,seed=30))(layer2)
layer4 = Dense(8,activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(0,1,seed=30))(layer3)
layer5 = Dense(4,activation='tanh',kernel_initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(0,1,seed=30))(layer4)

output = Dense(2,activation='softmax',kernel_initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(0,1,seed=30))(layer5)
model = Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs=output)
terminateNAN = TerminateNaN()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1,momentum=0.9)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=3, validation_data=(X_test,Y_test), batch_size=16 ,callbacks=[terminateNAN])
```

I have typacasted the output of get_weights() to numpy array. Yet i see the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Did some research and found out that the `isnan` works only with numpy native float types, not the object types. But in my case, the values are indeed float32 as shown below:

```
Type of weights <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
Weights:::: [array([[-9.7659566e-03,  8.8743661e-03,  ....]],dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to check whether any of the weights of the model is NaN. The function get_weights() returns a list of numpy arrays. Each array can have different dimensions depending on number of inputs and nodes in each layer. So I am not sure what happens when you cast this list to numpy array. I tried to do the same and got the same TypeError.

If you are only interested in knowing if there is a NaN in your weights I suggest the following:
`np.any([np.any(np.isnan(x)) for x in mdl.get_weights()])`

This will return True if any weight is NaN. Otherwise it will return False.

So in your code it will look like:

```
import numpy as np

class TerminateNaN(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):        
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        mod_weights = model.get_weights()
        if mod_weights is not None:
            if np.any([np.any(np.isnan(x)) for x in mod_weights]):
              print("Invalid weight and terminated at epoch {}".format(epoch))
              self.model.stop_training = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Thom. It worked just fine. The sizing issue dint ocur to me. I was looking at the problem from a different perspective.